# Silicon labs: compiler optimization bug?

Tags: c, optimization, microcontroller, 32-bit

I'm using the Silicon Labs BGM111-A module, with starter kit and for my project I need to use the UART.
At the start of my application I init the UART and start the reception with driver functions:

```
.
.
.
static UARTDRV_HandleData_t handleDataUart;
.
.
.
void IPP_Init(te_INIT_STATEs init_state)
{
    Ecode_t res;
    UARTDRV_InitUart_t initData;
    .
    .
    .
    // Initialize driver handle
    res=UARTDRV_InitUart(&handleDataUart,&initData);
    //Start receive 1 byte at time.
    res=UARTDRV_Receive(&handleDataUart,&pktBufRx[iPktBufRx],1,IPP_ReceivedData);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I set, in Simplicity Studio, compiler optimization at "None (-O0)" all work fine, but if I set optimization at "Optimize more (-O2)" the "UARTDRV_InitUart" function exit at the beginning when check if "handle" parameter (handleDataUart pointer) is NULL:

```
Ecode_t UARTDRV_InitUart(UARTDRV_Handle_t handle,
                         const UARTDRV_InitUart_t *initData)
{
  Ecode_t retVal;
  CORE_DECLARE_IRQ_STATE;
  USART_InitAsync_TypeDef usartInit = USART_INITASYNC_DEFAULT;

  if (handle == NULL) {
    return ECODE_EMDRV_UARTDRV_ILLEGAL_HANDLE;
.
.
.
```

I noticed (by the watch of address of "handle" parameter) that when the optimization is "-O2" the address of "handle" is "$R6" (CPU register), otherwise with optimization "-O0" the address is a RAM location. Could be this the problem?

It's a compiler bug or I have to edit my code?

Comment: when the code crashes after an optimization flag change, it often means that there's a problem in your code. Where is `handleDataUart` initialized in your main function?

Comment: you're passing `&handleDataUart` which is the address of a `static` variable. That _cannot_ be null. Have you checked the value of this pointer in the main routine? and if you disassembled it, have you disassembled the main routine as well to see if R6 is used when passing the parameters?

Comment: `handleDataUart` is initialize by `UARTDRV_InitUart` with `initData` structure.

`handleDataUart` is `static` and the pointer can't be null but the `UARTDRV_InitUart` function is implmented by silicon labs.

The R6 is used only when passing paramenters.

Comment: okay. So this is just not possible, since `handle` is the address of a static variable. Can you print the address of this variable before calling the function? if the address is different between caller and callee, then the compiler is probably at fault.

Comment: The address of `handleDataUart` before calling the function is 0x20004268 and inside the function the `handle`parameter has R6 address. For me the problem is not the different address (sometimes compiler use CPU regist for optimize) also because the content of R6 is 0x20004268, but the check if NULL. The disassembly instruction of check is `cbz     r6,0x00023558` and the value of R6 is 0x20004268  (the address of `handleDataUart `).

Comment: What are the exact definitions for `UARTDRV_HandleData_t` (the type of `handleDataUart`)  and `UARTDRV_Handle_t` that the function receives?

Comment: `UARTDRV_HandleData_t` is a big structure and `UARTDRV_Handle_t` is so defined: `typedef UARTDRV_HandleData_t * UARTDRV_Handle_t;`

Comment: typedefs on pointers are very confusing, as you may have noticed.

Comment: so I suppose that `cbz r6,0x00023558` branches if null, but it doesn't, since r6 is _not_ null. Have you stepped using a asm-level debugger to see how this instruction behaves?

Comment: Regard to CBZ instruction at this [link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaghefc.html) there is the follow note:

_There are no ARM or 32-bit Thumb versions of these instructions._

The problem could be that there are no ARM or 32-bit Thumb versions of these instructions?

Comment: LucaG: oh, if you're selecing the wrong target AND optimize then the compiler could choose instructions not in the real target set. I saw that once.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre: the target is correct otherwise I could not even program it.

Comment: I mean: the compiler could be set for a slightly different processor (with more instructions). Optimizer could select those instructions, unaware that your actual processor doesn't understand those instructions. When you say "function fails at the beginning when check if "handle" parameter (handleDataUart pointer) is NULL" you mean that the pointer is NULL or that the program crashes with "illegal instruction" or such?

Comment: No, "function fail" mean that the check if "handle" parameter is NULL exec the return instruction.

Comment: A guess would be that somewhere in the program, there's a memory corruption bug which fries the stack. When you enable optimizations, the compiler may inline the function call, meaning that the stack allocation of parameters does perhaps not take place during function call, but earlier, giving the rest of the program more time to bug out between the point where `&handleDataUart` is stored on the stack and the `handle == NULL` code. Less likely reason would be stack overflow. Try to debug the code with optimizations enabled and follow the disassembly.

Comment: The content of R6 is correct  (0x20004268 the address of handleDataUart) but the `CBZ` jump to 0x00023558 instruction.

Comment: You use a static global, but then pass it around in parameters using pointers.  C is pass by value, so the compiler is  optimizing out the possibility that the init function changes your data since it isn't marked `volatile`.  Either mark it volatile or get rid of the global variable and pass it around in a context.

Comment: @LucaG if the value is correct and the code jumps anyway, it's not a compiler problem. The CPU is probably ok, so it's your interpretation of what it does. Note that "it jumps" could be okay, if it jumps to skip the "return invalid" instruction, okay, cbz probably means "branch if zero".

Comment: @technosaurus: I tried to mark `volatile` (with and without `static`) but nothing change.

@Jean-François Fabre: it's not correct because it jumps to 0x00023558  and exit function but R6 is not zero.

Comment: @LucaG so you're implying that the _processor_ isn't working properly?

Comment: @LucaG can you post the (optimized version) disassembly of `UARTDRV_InitUart` ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suppose that compiler use `CBZ` asm instruction and convert it in an OPCODE but as it seems that it's not avilable for 32 bit ([link](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjaghefc.html)), the processor make other instruction.

Comment: @LucaG no it's possible with assemblers, not possible when disassembling.